# Do some VTK Library files contain errors?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, vtk

I managed to install vtk on my ubuntu. I'm using code::Blocks as compiler, working in c++. I also compiled and ran some of the examples given in the vtk examples web page. But at some examples, for example when vtkChart.h is involved, my compiler gives errors which refer to the content of the file.

These header files are generated automatically and should contain no errors. You can check the image below. What may be wrong? Is it caused by the compiler?

Thank your all.

[image]

For those who can't see the picture, the code is given below:

```
#ifndef __vtkChart_h
#define __vtkChart_h

#include "vtkContextItem.h"

class vtkTransform2D;
class vtkContext2D;
class vtkContextScene;
class vtkPlot;
class vtkAxis;
class vtkTextProperty;

class vtkInteractorStyle;
class vtkAnnotationLink;
class vtkTable;

class VTK_CHARTS_EXPORT vtkChart : public vtkContextItem
{
public:
  vtkTypeMacro(vtkChart, vtkContextItem);
  virtual void PrintSelf(ostream &os, vtkIndent indent);
```

just for the code segment shown, errors below show up.

../VTK-build/VTK-5.6/VTK/Charts/vtkChart.h|38|error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token|

../VTK-build/VTK-5.6/VTK/Charts/vtkChart.h|40|error: ‘vtkContextItem’ does not name a type|

../VTK-build/VTK-5.6/VTK/Charts/vtkChart.h|40|error: ‘vtkContextItem’ has not been declared|

../VTK-build/VTK-5.6/VTK/Charts/vtkChart.h|40|error: invalid static_cast from type ‘vtkObjectBase*’ to type ‘vtkChart*’|

../VTK-build/VTK-5.6/VTK/Charts/vtkChart.h||In member function ‘virtual vtkObjectBase* vtkChart::NewInstanceInternal() const’:|

../VTK-build/VTK-5.6/VTK/Charts/vtkChart.h|40|error: ‘New’ is not a member of ‘vtkChart’|

and goes on..

Comment: I can't see anything on the image as it is scaled. I really don't think that vtk has faulty headers, it's more likely that your configuration is wrong or missing something.

Comment: @RedX I tried to copy-paste some of the code segment. It makes also no sense vtk may contain headers like this but i can see no solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, Code::Blocks is not a compiler, it's an IDE that uses GCC or MSVC as a compiler. So, this should be more generic to GCC itself (since you appear to be using Ubuntu).

Your problem looks like a configuration error. `../VTK-build/VTK-5.6/VTK/Charts/vtkChart.h|40|error: ‘vtkContextItem’ does not name a type|`
is the kind of error that occurs when the compiler couldn't find vtkContextItem.h. Were there any errors above that say something like "vtkContextItem.h not found"?

Try using CMake to configure your project if you aren't already doing so. Generally CMake will do a better job of setting up the configuration than you could by yourself.

Comment: sorry for the misussage of words, my compiler is GCC. But the same thing also happens while using the Visual Studio. The only library that causes trouble is vtkCharts. In both platforms, I couldn't manage to work with this library even though they exist in their proper locations.

Comment: Right... I'll take a look in my vtk5.6 install later. Right now, I have access only to the master version, so I can't test vtkCharts on it.

Comment: OK, I tried this on 5.6 using VS 2008, and it doesn't seem to make much of a difference; the file includes quite sanely.

Could you try to just include vtkChart.h and see if that by itself compiles?

Comment: i rebuilt VTK and suffer no more of this problem. thank you shash.